# converting SETOF into a string

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

The function `json_object_keys(json)` returns a `setof text`. How do I transform this `setof text` to a string with all elements separated by a `','` ? I have to use the function `array_to_string()` but it accepts an array, and not a `setof`. So how do I convert a `setof` to array. For example:

```
DECLARE 
    custom_fields   json;
BEGIN
    custom_fields:='{"name":"John Smith","age":23}';
    keys:=array_to_string(json_object_keys(custom_fields),','::text);
END
```

The above doesnt work, I am getting:

```
ERROR:  function array_to_string(text, text) does not exist
```

So, how do I convert a `SETOF` to an `ARRAY`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `json_object_keys()` is a set-returning function, so you should use it as a row source (= in a `FROM` clause). With the `string_agg()` function you then get your result:

```
SELECT string_agg(cf, ',') INTO keys
FROM json_object_keys(custom_fields) jok(cf);
```

Note that this only works in a PL/pgSQL function because of the `INTO` clause.